# Can I remove dependencies from dependencies via composer?

Tags: 8, composer, distributions

If for example I have a distribution like thunder installed but I don’t want to have certain modules required via composer. Is there a way I can overwrite the dependencies of the distribution via my own projects composer.json?

This for example would be my project composer.json:
https://github.com/BurdaMagazinOrg/thunder-project/blob/2.x/composer.json

This would be the distributions composer.json:
https://github.com/BurdaMagazinOrg/thunder-distribution/blob/8.x-2.x/composer.json

And I want to remove drupal/adsense. Is that even possible?

Comment: This isn't drupal specific, you can use replace for that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637657/its-possible-ignore-child-dependency-in-composer-config.